# Is Wt leaking memory?

Tags: c++, wt

I just started to work with [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), and it seems that memory used by 
the program is constantly increasing (as shown by System Monitor on Ubuntu). 
This happens in many different contexts, event though the destructors are invoked.

My guess is that Wt is keeping copies of some data, and I wonder if there is a way to 
force Wt to free that memory.

The simplest example (appended below) is an app that 
creates/deletes a WText with a huge string. Calling create/delete slots multiple times
causes a constant memory increase. For fun, I added two buttons that call those slots from the browser.

Here is the code

```
#include <Wt/WApplication.h>
#include <Wt/WBreak.h>
#include <Wt/WContainerWidget.h>
#include <Wt/WPushButton.h>
#include <Wt/WText.h>

using namespace Wt;
class App: public Wt::WApplication
{
public:
    App(const Wt::WEnvironment& env);
private:
    static std::string  createHugeString();

    void createWText()
    { if(!m_widgetPtr)
        m_widgetPtr=this->root()->addNew<Wt::WText>(createHugeString());
    }

    void deleteWText()
    {  if(m_widgetPtr)
         auto uptr=root()->removeChild(m_widgetPtr);
         // will be deleted by unique_ptr dtor
       m_widgetPtr=nullptr;
    }

    Wt::WWidget *m_widgetPtr = nullptr;
};


App::App(const Wt::WEnvironment& env)
    :Wt::WApplication(env)
{
    auto *createTextButtonPtr = root()->addNew<WPushButton>("Create WText");
    auto *delTextButtonPtr = root()->addNew<WPushButton>("Delete WText");
    root()->addNew<WBreak>();

    createTextButtonPtr->clicked().connect(this,&App::createWText);
    delTextButtonPtr->clicked().connect(this,&App::deleteWText);
} //constructor


std::string App::createHugeString()
{
    std::string htmlStr;
    for(std::size_t i =0; i!=20000000/4; ++i){
        htmlStr += "a b ";
    }
    return htmlStr;
}


int main()
{
    char* argv[]= {"progname", "--docroot", "." ,
                   "--http-address", "0.0.0.0",
                   "--http-port", "8080"
                   };
    int argc = sizeof(argv)/sizeof(*argv);

    return Wt::WRun(argc, argv, [](const Wt::WEnvironment& env) {
      return std::make_unique<App>(env);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you ever free the object pointed to by `m_widgetPtr`? It just looks like you remove it from some list of widgets. If not, that could be a memory leak. You should probably run a tool designed to detect memory leaks - such as [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Compiling with `-fsanitize=address` is several times faster than valgrind (and more accurate), but occasionally tricky to set up.

Comment: There is a comment in the code `// will be deleted by unique_ptr dtor` but there are no `unique_ptr` instances anywhere.

Comment: @fredrik  root()->removeChild() returns temporary unique_ptr that deletes WText ptr

Comment: @fredrik it's from a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Wt::WWidget>>`

Answer (score 1):

`createHugeString()` would probably increase memory usage, even without leak: you fragment the memory.

`reserve` correct dimension for `htmlStr` should avoid some fragmentations.

Comment: I did that, and even replaced createHugeString()  by reference to (properly reserved)  string with static storage duration. But the problem stil remains.

Comment: System Monitor is not really the right tool for memory leak. 2 better alternatives are already be suggested in comments. And as I state, we might have increasing consumption without memory leak.